# Tease or tease with?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to know which phrase would be grammatically correct?

Should I use;

> I was teasing you.

OR

> I was teasing with you.

Comment: _tease you_ is correct; you could say _I was teasing you_ or _I was teasing._ Why this is so has to do with _transitivity/intransitivity._

Comment: I teased **the cat** _with_ a piece of string. I teased **Mary** _with_ jokes about her dress.

Answer (score -1):

If "you" is the object of the teasing, then "I was teasing you".

The only time "I was teasing with you" could be used would be if you and I were teasing somebody else together as a team: "I was teasing Jane with you".

Comment: It's common to use "with" to express the object (thing in a patient role) of an adjective, e.g. "I was playful with you" means "I acted in a playful manner towards you". It's also possible to use the participle "teasing" in a similar way, even though it's not a full adjective. But teasing can also be used as part of a verb with a direct object "I was teasing you".

Comment: @StuartF The natural and idiomatic way of expressing this (and the answer to the question) is "I was teasing you". If somebody said "I was teasing with you", they would immediately sound like English was not their first language -- this type of prepositional confusion is a common clue. While I understand your point, your comment here is difficult to parse even to me as a native speaker and I believe more likely to mislead than help. Feel free to clarify/simplify your point though. (There also may be some regional differences, but I don't think that was your point)